# cannot find symbol: Hbox, Vbox

Tags: java, javafx

I'm running JavaFx on fedora using the following commandline:
`javac --module-path $JAVAFX_HOME --add modules javafx.controls AudioPlaylist.java`

to which it gives me these errors:

```
AudioPlaylist.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
        VBoxBuilder.create().children(
  symbol:   variable VBoxBuilder
  location: class AudioPlaylist
AudioPlaylist.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
        HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(next, play, stop, prog, mediaView).build()
        ^
  symbol:   variable HBoxBuilder
  location: class AudioPlaylist
5 errors
```

I searched online and it didn't solve my problem as I am still unable to run the program.
Which is why I am asking on here.
Code i'm trying to run:
https://pastebin.com/tTpFBQw7

Comment: You need `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.media`

Comment: @James_D Thanks; it resolved the other errors which caused the media not visible issue 
any idea about the Hbox and Vbox error?

Comment: The builder classes were removed in version 9.

Comment: @James_D So is there an alternative or a solution?

Comment: Just instantiate the `HBox` and `VBox` in the normal way.

Comment: @James_D the normal way as in? sorry if im asking, im just trying to learn

Comment: _im just trying to learn_ first step is to work through a current tutorial on javafx (as @James_D already noted, the builders were removed many years ago - a tutorial still using them in examples is definitely very out-dated)

Comment: Just instantiate `HBox` and `VBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the builder class anymore as you did in your example, since the class got removed. So your code won't work anymore:

```
HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(next, play, stop, prog, mediaView).build()
```

You have to make it like this:

```
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.setSpacing(10);
hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
hbox.getChildren().add(next, play, stop, prog, mediaView);
```

Same goes for the VBox. Since the Builder Classes were removed a long time ago, I also would recommend you to use a different tutorial to learn JavaFX.